# Typo3 FAL: file search in backend

Tags: file, search, typo3, backend, abstraction

I'm building an extension for a Typo3 6.1 site, which uses FAL.
This extension works with a lot of files, so a search function would be very helpful, but I can't find it anywhere.
Do, does FAL have any search function in backend for Typo3 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, FAL does not have a file search implemented.

But you can use Extension "Media" (Key: media) which offers search and filter functionality. In the configuration of the extension you can define whether you want to use Media or "FAL" (the normal file picker) als Media Element Browser (when linking to files).

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of implementing a search on the files, then your repository should extend `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository` which is basically a mapper to the `sys_file` table.
This return a FileReference object or a list of FileReference objects, when looking up for something in the table.

FileRepository.php:
http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_file_repository_8php_source.html

FileReference.php:
http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/core_2_classes_2_resource_2_file_reference_8php_source.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this old question: **You can recursively search for files/folders**  in backend module filelist **since TYPO3 version 7LTS**.